# Invoking WCF service from a hyperlink in an email

Tags: c#, wcf

You know the scenario....You are adding functionality to your system to send out an email to validate a users email.  Typically the email will contain a hyperlink which will request a page in your application - passing appropriate information - to determine that a user has validated their email....

I want to forgo adding a dedicated page to application to do this, and take as few steps as possible to invoke a service to do what I explained above.  What steps can I take to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `webHttpBinding` and use a path like the following

`http://YourServer/YourApp/YourService/MethodName[?parameters]`

NOTE: you would have to set the `Method="GET"` on the methods that you want to invoke using `WebGetAttribute` or `WebInvokeAttribute` along with the `OperationContractAttribute`.